# Using \@author variable to put authors name in fancy header

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, titles

I'm using `\@author` variable to put authorname in header of my document. Currently, header shows authorname and footnotemark which incerements every page:

```
\makeatletter
\let\runauthor\@author
\let\runtitle\@title
\makeatother

\fancyhead[OC]{\runauthor}
\fancyhead[EC]{\sc \runtitle}
```

For example, if author is John Doe, I get printed

```
John Doe^1 (1.page)
John Doe^2 (2.page)
...
etc.
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your code works here. Without a MWE, it is hard to tell what is going wrong. I have added an alternative solution as an answer, can you try that and let us know if it works? (I'll delete it if this is not what you are after)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fluently.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{authoraftertitle}

\makeatletter
\fancyhead[OC]{{\let\thanks\@gobble\MyAuthor}}
\fancyhead[EC]{\scshape \MyTitle}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatother

\title{TTT}
\author{AAA\thanks{THXTHX}}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not if the `\author` command contains also address information: `\author{AAA\\bbb\\ccc}`

Answer (score 5):

As egreg suggests, your problem may be related to the presence of other macros in the `\author` command, perhaps something like `\author{John Doe\thanks{Mum and Dad}}`. It is difficult to tell without a full MWE (in particular, what document class you are using and how you are calling `\author`).
However, a solution which should work is to use the `titling` package:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titling}

\author{John Doe}
\title{My Title}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[OC]{\theauthor}
\fancyhead[EC]{\scshape \thetitle}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP's problem is quite probably in something like `\author{A. Uthor\thanks{Ducks}}`; the `titling` package should indeed take care of this: maybe you could try adding it to your code. Please, use `\scshape` and not `\sc`.

Comment: Ok. the idea behind all this is that I am using pdfpages to produce  binder for several articles. I use my own class definition and in it I use \author variable to specify author name in the header. In other words, I don't want to hard code author's name. And I think you made a point why this problem is occuring.

Comment: @egreg Yes, that is likely. Thanks for spotting the `\sc`, I just copy-pasted from the OP's post but I definitely agree about using `\scshape`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if the `\author` command contains also address information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not happy with any of the packaged solutions, you can always write your own, like I did.  The example here uses standard article class margins, which my stamper was not designed for.  But it still looks OK, and you have control over all the parameters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
%% SET UP CODE TO USE PAGE STAMPS AT TOP AND BOTTOM OF PAGE.  DEFAULT
%% STAMP IS "DRAFT", BUT IT CAN BE RESET AND USED FOR OTHER PURPOSES,
%% TOO.
\def\PageStampFlag{F}
\def\thePageStamp{}
\def\EmptyStyle{empty}
\def\PlainStyle{plain}

\newcommand{\ps@pagestamp}{
  \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\hfil\textbf{\Large\thePageStamp}\hfil}
  \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
  \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\hfil
                            \begin{tabular}{c}
                            \textrm{\thepage}\\
                            \textbf{\Large\thePageStamp}
                            \end{tabular}
                            \hfil}
  \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\@evenfoot}
}

\newcommand{\ps@emptypagestamp}{
  \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\hfil\textbf{\Large\thePageStamp}\hfil}
  \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
  \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\hfil
                            \begin{tabular}{c}
                            ~\\
                            \textbf{\Large\thePageStamp}
                            \end{tabular}
                            \hfil}
  \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\@evenfoot}
}

\newcommand\PageStamp[1][DRAFT]{
  \def\PageStampFlag{T}
  \setlength\textheight{9in} %textheight+headheight+headsep=9in
  \def\thePageStamp{#1}
  \setlength\topmargin{-1.0in}
  \setlength\headheight{0.6in}
  \setlength\headsep{0.4in}
  \setlength\footskip{38pt}
  \def\PlainStyle{pagestamp}
  \def\EmptyStyle{emptypagestamp}
  \pagestyle{\PlainStyle}
}

\newcommand\StopPageStamp[0]{
  \def\PageStampFlag{F}
  \setlength\topmargin{0in}
  \setlength\headheight{0pt}
  \setlength\headsep{0pt}
  \setlength\textheight {9.0in}
  \setlength\footskip{30pt}
  \def\PlainStyle{plain}
  \def\EmptyStyle{empty}
  \pagestyle{\PlainStyle}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\PageStamp[\today]

This is a test of Steven's pagestamping commands. Usage is
\verb|\PageStamp[stamp]|.  Default stamp is ``DRAFT''.  The command can
be reissued to change the pagestamp.  The alternate command
\verb|\StopPageStamp| will suspend the pagestamp, unless/until later
reinstituted with a \verb|\PageStamp[]|

\end{document}
```

[image]